# Tesseract - Help me understand datapath

Tags: android, android-camera, ocr, tesseract

Can someone explain what exactly is going on and how I can rectify it.  So I understand tesseract has to have an image to target and presumably this would be the bitmap I've captured and tried to save.  That saved location would be my _path variable.  Now what is the DATA_PATH for tesseract? Does the image need to be stored in a folder called 'tesseract' ? Do I create that folder and store some kind of training in it? I'm looking for an explanation rather than a code example.

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ - I am trying to follow this tutorial and checking others to try and understand the paths which all of them use.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static ImageView imageView;
protected String _path;
// protected static Bitmap bit;
static File myDir;
protected static Bitmap mImageBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    _path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/test.bmp";

    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HEELLLLLLOO", 100000);
    t.show();
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // CALL THE PICTURE
            dispatchTakePictureIntent(0);

        }
    });
}

private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    //_path = path to the image to be OCRed
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(_path);

    int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    int rotate = 0;
    switch (exifOrientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    }
    if (rotate != 0) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        // Setting pre rotate
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(rotate);
        // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }



    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
    // lang for which the language data exists, usually "eng"
    baseApi.init(_path, "eng");  //THIS SHOULD BE DATA_PATH ?
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    System.out.println(recognizedText);
    baseApi.end();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}

protected static void identifyunicode() {
    // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
    // lang for which the language data exists, usually "eng"

    /*
     * TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
     * baseApi.init(myDir.toString(), "eng"); // myDir + //
     * "/tessdata/eng.traineddata" // must be present baseApi.setImage(bit);
     * String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text(); // Log or otherwise //
     * display this // string... baseApi.end();
     */
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`DataPath` is the path where you copied your `tessdata` files from `Assets`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Environment;

public class Utils {

    public static boolean isSDCardMounted() {
        boolean isMounted = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_NOFS.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            isMounted = false;
        }
        return isMounted;
    }

    public static boolean isDirectoryExists(final String filePath) {
        boolean isDirectoryExists = false;
        File mFilePath = new File(filePath);
        if(mFilePath.exists()) {
            isDirectoryExists = true;
        } else {
            isDirectoryExists = mFilePath.mkdirs();
        }
        return isDirectoryExists;
    }

    public static boolean deleteFile(final String filePath) {
        boolean isFileExists = false;
        File mFilePath = new File(filePath);
        if(mFilePath.exists()) {
            mFilePath.delete();
            isFileExists = true;
        }
        return isFileExists;
    }

    public static String getDataPath() {
        String returnedPath = "";
        final String mDirName = "tesseract";
        final String mDataDirName = "tessdata";
        if(isSDCardMounted()) {
            final String mSDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + mDirName;
            if(isDirectoryExists(mSDCardPath)) {
                final String mSDCardDataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + mDirName + 
                        File.separator + mDataDirName;
                isDirectoryExists(mSDCardDataPath);
                return mSDCardPath;
            }
        }
        return returnedPath;
    }
}
```

`Activity` Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class AndroidCommonTest extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = AndroidCommonTest.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView txtGotTime = null;
    private final int START_CODE = 101;
    private String mDirPath = null;
    private Uri mOutPutUri = null;
    private static final String lang = "eng";
    private String mPath = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtGotTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGotTime);

        mDirPath = Utils.getDataPath();
        mPath = mDirPath + File.separator + "test.jpg";
        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "mDirPath: " + mDirPath + " mPath: " + mPath);

        if (!(new File(mDirPath + File.separator + "tessdata" + File.separator + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {
                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata" + File.separator + lang + ".traineddata");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mDirPath + File.separator 
                        + "tessdata" + File.separator + lang + ".traineddata");
                byte[] buf = new byte[8024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            processImage(mDirPath + File.separator + "six.jpg", 0);
        }
    }

    public void getTime(View view) {
        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "mDirPath: " + mDirPath + " mPath: " + mPath);
        if(mDirPath != null && mDirPath.length() > 0) {
            mOutPutUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutPutUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, START_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == START_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int rotation = -1;
                long fileSize = new File(mPath).length();
                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "fileSize " + fileSize);

                //Suppose Device Supports ExifInterface
                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(mPath);
                    int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    switch (exifOrientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 :
                            rotation = 90;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 :
                            rotation = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 :
                            rotation = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                            rotation = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Exif:rotation " + rotation);

                    if (rotation != -1) {
                        processImage(mPath, rotation);
                    } else {
                        //Device Does Not Support ExifInterface
                        Cursor mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(mOutPutUri,
                                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION, 
                                MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE },
                                null, null, null);
                        if (mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.getCount() != 0 ) {
                            while(mediaCursor.moveToNext()){
                                long size = mediaCursor.getLong(1);
                                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Media:size " + size);
                                if(size == fileSize){
                                    rotation = mediaCursor.getInt(0);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Media:rotation " + rotation);
                            processImage(mPath, rotation);
                        } else {
                            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Android Problem");
                            txtGotTime.setText("Android Problem");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
                txtGotTime.setText("RESULT_CANCELED");
            }
        }
    }

    private void processImage(final String filePath, final int rotation) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            baseApi.setDebug(true);
            baseApi.init(mDirPath, lang);
            baseApi.setPageSegMode(100);
            baseApi.setPageSegMode(7);
            baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
            String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "recognizedText: 1 " + recognizedText);
            baseApi.end();
            if(lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
                recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
            }
            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "recognizedText: 2 " + recognizedText.trim());
            txtGotTime.setText(recognizedText.trim());
        }
    }

    private void saveImageAndroid(final Bitmap passedBitmap) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mDirPath  + File.separator + "savedAndroid.jpg");
            passedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Put `tessdata` folder in `Assets`.

Do not forget to give reference path of `Tess Library`.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay you say to put tessdata folder in Assets, Where is the tessdata folder? I'm looking at the tesstwo directory and I don't see it.

Comment: Ah I downloaded a training set for Tesseract which included the tessdata folder however, now my application crashes on run.
"Asset path /data/app/com.example.cameraocr-2.apk is neither a directory or nor file (type =1)

Comment: @user1088595 Did you see my code? I am copying that `eng.traineddata` file from Assets to my created Dir.